# Mac OS X Open Source equivelent to QuicKeys

Tags: macos, macros

Hey there all, I'm looking for a free(as in speech) equivalent to [QuicKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/)
If I'm lucky it'll also be free(as in beer)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is it in QuicKeys that you're trying to get?  If you just want automation, but sans the nice authoring environment, AppleScript can control almost anything QuicKeys can - if you want the nice authoring environment, user experience tends not to be the thing that opens source developers focus on.

Comment: I'm looking for the ability to bind to a key command, such as typing alt-command-shift-x for example runs a particular applescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/) can do that. I myself mapped my F5 key to an AppleScript that disables then re-enable Bluetooth.

I'm pretty sure [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) can too, but I've never used it myself. It's shareware (Quicksilver is freeware).

There is also [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), but it doesn't exactly do what you asked for above. But it's pretty fast to launch anything using Alfred and a couple of keystrokes. Plus, it's visually pleasing! There's a free version, and a paid version with [more features](http://www.alfredapp.com/powerpack/).